# How to prove that $3^\pi > \pi^3$

Tags: inequality

I need to prove this inequality that $3^\pi > \pi^3$ 
How can i start to answer this problem. What concept should I apply?

Comment: check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362247/is-ab-larger-than-ba-if-ab-and-a-b-1/1362256#1362256, right the first answer by Michael

Comment: That's trivial: $3^\pi > 3^{3.14} > 3.15^3 > \pi^3$. The middle inequality can be shown by calculation an the other by the fact that both $3^x$ and $x^3$ are increasing. The question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362247/is-ab-larger-than-ba-if-ab-and-a-b-1/1362256 is much more interresting as it's a general statement that cannot be proven by simply tapping on a calculator.

Answer (score 7):

One way is to prove that the function
$$
x\mapsto x^{1/x}
$$
is monotonically decreasing if $x>e$. I leave the details to you.

Answer (score 2):

I would write $\pi = 3 +\epsilon$, where $\epsilon \gt 0$.  Then rewrite as follows:

$$\begin{align}3^{\pi} &= 3^{3+\epsilon} = 3^3 \cdot 3^{\epsilon} = 3^3 \cdot e^{\epsilon \log{3}}\\ &\ge 3^3 \left (1+(\log{3}) \epsilon + \frac12 (\log{3})^2 \epsilon^2 +\frac16 (\log{3})^3 \epsilon^3\right ) \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\pi^3 = (3+\epsilon)^3 &= 3^3 + 3 \cdot 3^2 \epsilon + 3 \cdot 3 \epsilon^2+\epsilon^3\\ &= 3^3 \left  (1+\epsilon+\frac13 e^2 + \frac1{27} e^3 \right )\end{align}$$

What can you conclude from this?  NB $\log{3} \gt 1$.

You should also prove that $\log{3} \gt 1$ by showing that

$$\left ( 1+\frac1{n} \right )^n \lt 3 $$

for all $n$.

Comment: Oops, did not see you did almost the same thing.

Comment: Apparently, your answer was so close to mine that I edited your by mistake.  Whoops, sorry about that.

Comment: We all have or share of stress and make silly mistakes once in a while, it's ok ;)

Answer (score 2):

Take logarithms and use the fact that $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$ is strictly decreasing for $x>e$ while $\ln x, e^x$ are strictly increasing:

$$3 <  \pi$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{\ln 3}{3} >  \frac{\ln \pi}{\pi}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \pi \ln3 > 3 \ln \pi$$
$$\Longrightarrow 3^\pi > \pi^3$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $\pi = 3+\epsilon$, then by binomial theorem $$\pi^3 = 3^3+3\cdot3^2\epsilon + 3\cdot3^1\epsilon^2 + \epsilon^3$$
we can rewrite this as $$3^3(1+\epsilon+\epsilon^2/3 + \epsilon^3/3^2)$$

Then consider $3^\pi = 3^{(3+\epsilon)} = 3^3 3^\epsilon$

Now the taylor expansion for $3^\epsilon$ is $1 + \log(3)\epsilon + \log(3)^2\epsilon^2/2 + \log(3)^3\epsilon^3/6 + \cdots$

Pairwise comparison of terms, that all terms in exponential are non-negative and $\log(3)>1$ should show that the exponential is larger.